# How to resolve midi note sound issue?

Tags: ios

I am trying to play MIDI notes by loading sound font file for Piano,but I have an issue that its not producing proper note sound its regardless of octave notes.I am using MIKMIDI Library.Also I debugged and noticed that every note number is correct but not the sound.I am using following code which sends MIDI messages to an AudioUnit.Please can anyone help to get it solved.

```
- (void)handleMIDIMessages:(NSArray *)commands
 { 
    for (MIKMIDICommand *command in commands)
     {
     OSStatus err = MusicDeviceMIDIEvent(self.instrumentUnit,  command.statusByte, command.dataByte1, command.dataByte2,0); NSLog(@"%@",command); if (err) NSLog(@"Unable to send MIDI command to synthesizer %@: %@", command, @(err));
     }
 }
```

Comment: Mind providing the piece of code that's not working?

Comment: Yes I don't mind in providing code but I am not being able to find it out the exactly code that is causing an issue.

Comment: Please update your post with the code added on comment.

Comment: @aribeiro I have updated.